# This he interprets so that X happens

Tags: grammar

In Chapter 2 of *Ethics with Aristotle*, Broadie writes

> and this he interprets so that practical virtue (as ordinarily understood) becomes the focus of attention.

The sentence throws me off a bit because it doesn't seem to follow an obvious subject predicate structure. If "this" is the subject and "he interprets so" is a modifier, what then is the verb of the sentence?

Perhaps the quote doesn't have a verb and is not a sentence. In context, the whole sentence reads: "Aristotle's supreme good is the well functioning of the human being qua human; functioning well is nothing other than 'activity in accordance with virtue (or excellence)'; and this he interprets so that practical virtue (as ordinarily understood) becomes the focus of attention." But if the late part is only a phrase, what is the name of this type of phrases?

Comment: Ya, I have checked out that on wiki. But I don't see how it applies here. If anything it seems that the object of a verb is inverted not the subject.

Comment: Yes, and _this_ is the object of _interpret_. It refers to whatever was discussed in the preceding sentences. It's a way to bring them in again without restating everything. So the assumption that _this_ was the subject was natural when it starts a clause, but when you see the next noun phrase you know that was the wrong assumption and something else is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object *this* (which presumably refers to whatever comes before) is fronted - see ["Topicalization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization).

As Greybeard says, *so that* introduces an adverbial clause.

Answer (score 0):

> and this he interprets **so that** practical virtue (as ordinarily understood) becomes the focus of attention."

**so that** introduces an adverbial subordinate clause. "so that X" = "in such a way that X".